# Adding compound view class into view programatically in android

Tags: android, android-layout, composite-component

Hi I am trying to add compound view class into my view programmatically. But I don't know how to do that.
I can add directly it in to layout and thats working fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainLlt"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.example.androidcustomvliveapplication.widget.CustomCardSection 
    android:id="@+id/cardSection2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</com.example.androidcustomvliveapplication.widget.CustomCardSection> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Above thing working fine. But I want to add above composite layout programmatically. 
LIke I want to do like this

`mainLlt.add(customcardsection)`

Need Some help. Thank you.

```
public class CustomCardSection extends RelativeLayout
{

int section;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public CustomCardSection(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

public CustomCardSection(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyleAttr) 
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public CustomCardSection(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);

     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_card_section, this, true);
    }

public CustomCardSection(Context context) 
{
    super(context);
}
}
```

Comment: can you please post code of CustomCardSection ?

Comment: ok will do update my question.

Comment: Have you find the solution? can you please help me?